# Update Python version

Tags: ubuntu, python

When I type `python`, I get this:

[image]

When I type `find . -name \python*`, I get this:

[image]

When I type `locate -b \python`, I found this:

[image]

I do not understand why I have multiple versions of Python installed through my Ubuntu update, and I have the latest python 3.4 installed, yet when I use Python it still uses 2.7.6.

I come from Windows and is not too familiar with Linux yet.

Comment: Python 2 is still widely used and incompatible with Python 3.

Comment: Oh and please don't post screenshots if you can copy text.

Comment: I don’t get. Don’t you always want to use the latest verson? Like whe  you update a java runtime you won’t be keeping various version unless running old code? no?

Comment: Not when the versions are incompatible. Java is an interesting example because there were really times you might have needed to have Java 1.5 and 1.6 side-by-side if I remember correctly.

Comment: I recommend you update 2.7.6 to 2.7.12 which is latest version of Python2.   If you really like python3, you can link /usr/bin/python to python3, then default python will change to python3

Comment: @KMC Python 2 and 3 are not entirely compatible, some major changes have happened (right now off the top of my head: `print` is now a function and `map` and `range` return an iterator).

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand why I have multiple versions of Python installed through my Ubuntu update, and I have the latest python 3.4 installed, yet when I use Python it still uses 2.7.6.

Python 2 and 3 are [not entirely compatible](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) and many projects still use Python 2, so for now you need them both. You will usually specify which Python you want to use (in your code you need a `#!/usr/bin/python3` line).

For development usage, I usually prefer a `virtualenv` or a tool like [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and have a separate Python. Then the system's Python is not touched when I install a newer version of a library.